# How to change programmatically the application language in an eclipse application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, internationalization, eclipse-rcp

I have just done [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseInternationalization/article.html) tutorial on internationalisation and I am really happy with it. But I want to know, if I build a toolbar and provide some options for the user to change the language, how it would work in my application? I am sure that the application would need restarting, I'm expecting eclipse to provide dynamic behaviour for it. So no expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do it like this:

```
IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = new ScopedPreferenceStore(new InstanceScope(),getBundle().getSymbolicName());
preferenceStore.setValue("language", locale.toString()); //$NON-NLS-1$
getWorkbench().restart();
```

While you may obtain the locale from a parameterized Command bound to a handler, like:

```
public class ChangeLanguageHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IElementUpdater {

  private static final String PARAM = "lang"; //$NON-NLS-1$

  @Override
  public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    // Consider to supress deselection event:
    if (event.getTrigger() instanceof Event) {
      final Widget widget = ((Event) event.getTrigger()).widget;
      if (widget instanceof MenuItem) {
        if (!((MenuItem) widget).getSelection()) {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
    final Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event);
    final String lang = event.getParameter(PARAM);
    if (openDialogAndAskIfUserIsSureAboutThis_BecauseItRequiresARestart) {
      invokeCodeAboveWithTheNewLocale(new Locale(lang));
    }
    return null;
  }

  // Update the Checked State...
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Override
  public void updateElement(final UIElement element, final Map parameters) {
    final Object param = parameters.get(PARAM);
    element.setChecked(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals(param));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this blog posts:

http://blog.vogella.com/2013/05/03/eclipse-internationalization-part-14-current-situation-by-dirk-fauth/

There is a `org.eclipse.e4.core.services.nls.ILocaleChangeService` in the e4 environment, but you need to prepare your application for it.

Best download the source and have a look:
https://github.com/fipro78/e4translationexample

If you are not using e4 or don't mind a restart you can use this code (not tested):

```
    // set the eclipse relaunch property
    StringBuffer arguments = new StringBuffer();
    arguments.append("${eclipse.vm}\n"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    arguments.append("-nl\n").append("de").append("\n"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$

    arguments.append("-vmargs\n"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    arguments.append(System.getProperty("eclipse.vmargs")); //$NON-NLS-1$

    System.setProperty("eclipse.exitcode", Integer.toString(IApplication.EXIT_RELAUNCH)); //$NON-NLS-1$
    System.getProperties().setProperty(IApplicationContext.EXIT_DATA_PROPERTY, arguments.toString());
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();
```

Keep in mind that this does not work in your development environment, since restarts are not supported.

Comment: are you running from eclipse or a product?

Comment: tried both ways. no succsess. only thing working for me is to manipulate the config.ini in the product. But that would be a Little bit hacky which is why i am searching for a better solution

Comment: and your running the code above? have you modified the locale? arguments.append("-nl\n").append("de")...